# ODBC DB2 data fetch error (out of memory error)

Tags: php-7.2

I have connected ODBC to remote DB2 successfully, I'm able to insert data in a table but when fetching the data I'm getting PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 2097152) (tried to allocate 206158430219 bytes) error.
 i'm using, ubuntu 18, DB2 DSDrive fixpack 10, unixodbc v 2.3.4 , php v 7.2

i tested unixODBC using isql -v  , i'm able to fetch the data, but i'm only getting the problem when fetching using php script

I created another db2 instance and tried but I'm getting the same error

i tried to set the memory limit from 128M to 200M,in php.ini, still not worked

```
$conn = odbc_connect( $conn_string, "", "" );
if( $conn )
{
    echo "Connection succeeded.";
    $sql = "insert into testsam values('testname',20,'male');";
    $rs = odbc_exec($conn,$sql); // here i'm getting problem while using select * from testsam
    echo "<table><tr>";
    echo "<th>User Name $rs</th></tr>";
    #while (odbc_fetch_row($rs)){
    #   $user = odbc_result($rs,"NAME");
    #   print_r($user);
    #}
    if($rs){
        echo "data fetched";
    }
    odbc_close($conn);
    //echo "</table>";
    # Disconnect
    #
    #odbc_close( $conn );
}
else
{
    echo "Connection failed.";
}
```

Comment: the issue is been resolved, I was pointing to the wrong driver which support data insertion but not support data translation between driver and application. I was using  libdb2.so and now I'm using libdb2o.so it worked for me.